# How to hide suggested email id from keyboard in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to hide email suggestion which is displaying while i choose email textField in my application.

I have tried different options like below but none of them works for me.

```
txtEmail.autocorrectionType = .no
txtEmail.accessibilityLabel = .none
txtEmail.textContentType = .none
```

Is there anything else a part from this which i missed out ?

[image]

Comment: have you set at storyboard over textfield Text Input Traits Correction as NO ?

Comment: Yes, Correction is set NO, also Smart Insert is set NO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set UITextField text content type to an empty string:

```
txtEmail.textContentType = .init(rawValue: "")
```

Comment: Thanks man, This is working as i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how, but @Leo Dabus answer doesn't work in my case, however, an approach below does

```
        textView.autocorrectionType = .no
        textView.keyboardType = .emailAddress
```

I had to set `keyboardType` not to `.default`.